# Is there a way to maintain momentum while shifting gravity in a different direction?

Tags: gravity-rush

Is there a way to quickly change my direction while falling/shifting gravity so I maintain enough momentum for a high damaging gravity kick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience (based on the demo version), your best bet is to fall away from the enemy, towards open space, then after gaining some distance turn the camera around 180 degrees and press <kbd>■</kbd> to launch towards the enemy. If you need to adjust your direction mid-flight, I recommend you press <kbd>■</kbd> again (without stopping in mid air), as long as you generally keep flying in the original direction you'll keep your forward momentum (i.e. if you start your attack again mid flight, it won't be from zero speed)

Comment: hmm... so its possible to use kicks to change my direction?

Comment: Yes kicking in the air is the best way to switch direction without having to float and aim.